# Webpack: Make dependency using another dependency instead of its own subdependency

Tags: javascript, dependency-management, webpack

I am using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) to build my app and I use a library ([eventemitter4](https://github.com/eriksank/eventemitter4)) that itself depends on another library ([underscore](http://underscorejs.org)).

However, I am already using in my application an alternative to [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) ([lodash](https://lodash.com) and more exactly the es6 version).
I would like [eventemitter4](https://github.com/eriksank/eventemitter4) to use this later library and avoid including in my build the two.

I install my dependencies using `npm install`. As a result, [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) is bundled as a subdirectory inside the [eventemitter4](https://github.com/eriksank/eventemitter4)'s directory.

It tried to set aliases but I could not make it work:

```
alias: {
  "underscore": "lodash-es",
  "lodash": "lodash-es",
  "~/underscore": "lodash-es"
}
```

raises

```
ERROR in ./~/eventemitter4/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'lodash-es' in /Users/me/myapp/node_modules/eventemitter4
@ ./~/eventemitter4/index.js 6:2-23
```

If I do not add `"~/underscore": "lodash-es"`, the sub-[underscore](http://underscorejs.org) is included instead of [lodash](https://lodash.com).

Any idea?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the reason. The alias was working. The cause of the error was that `lodash-es` does not provide a `main` attribute in his `package.json` (it only provides an `esnext:main` which is not recognised by webpack).

I solve the issue by using:

```
alias: {
  "underscore": "lodash-es",
  "lodash": "lodash-es/lodash",
  "~/underscore": "lodash-es"
}
```